# form validation not working for phone number/name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have been trying to make a form that validates phone number and name, but whenever submit is entered it just inputs the same messages whether the fields are filled out or not. The message constantly appears and I can't figure it out

ETA: http://jsfiddle.net/6W3uU/

```
<body>
<form id="contact">
<fieldset id="contactInformation">
<legend>Contact Information</legend>
<p id="error"></p>
<label id="name">Name:</label>
<br>
<input type="text">
<br>
<br>
<label id="phoneNumber">Phone Number:</label>
<br>
<input type="text">
<br>
<br>
<label id="eMail">E-Mail Address:</label>
<br>
<input type="text">
<br>
<br>
<label id="address">Address:</label>
<br>
<input type="text">
<br>
<br>
<label id="city">City:</label>
<br>
<input type="text">
<br>
<br>
<label id="postalCode">Postal Code:</label>
<br>
<input type="text">
<br>
<br>
<label id="province">Province</label>
<br>
<select id="province">
<option id="choose">Choose Your Province</option>
<option id="alberta">Alberta</option>
<option id="britishColumbia">British Columbia</option>
<option id="manitoba">Manitoba</option>
<option id="newBrunswick">New Brunswick</option>
<option id="newfoundland">Newfoundland and Labrador</option>
<option id="northwestTerritories">Northwest Territories</option>
<option id="noviaScotia">Nova Scotia</option>
<option id="nunavut">Nunavut</option>
<option id="ontario">Ontario</option>
<option id="pei">Prince Edward Island</option>
<option id="quebec">Quebec</option>
<option id="saskatchewan">Saskatchewan</option>
<option id="yukon">Yukon Territory</option>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<label id="shippingCheckbox">Is your shipping information the same as your contact information?
<input type="radio" id="sameInfo">
<label>
Yes it is
</label>
<br>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="notSameInfo">
<label>
No it is not
</label>
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<br>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the script:

```
//script.js
var errorNotify = 'Sorry, we could not process your request because '
var errorField = [];

function formVal() {
    var isValid = true;

    for (var i = 0; i < errorField.length; i++ ) {
        $(errorField[i]).removeClass('error');
    }
    errorField = [];

    if(!nameCheck()) {
        isValid = false;
    }
    if(!phoneCheck()) {
        isValid = false;
    }
    if (isValid === false) {
        $('#error').html(errorNotify).hide().slideDown('slow');
        for (var i = 0; i < errorField.length; i++) {
            $(errorField[i]).addClass('error');
        }
        errorNotify = 'Sorry, we could not process your request because ';
    }

    function nameCheck(){
        if ($('#name').val() === '') {
            errorNotify += ' you did not enter your name.';
            errorField.push($('#name'));
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    function phoneCheck(){
        var phoneCheck = $('#phoneNumber').val();
        if (phoneCheck === '') {
            errorNotify += ' you did not enter your phone number.';
            errorField.push($('#phoneNumber'));
            return false;
        } else if (phoneCheck.length !== 10) {
            errorNotify += 'please enter a 10 digit phone number';
            errorField.push($('#phoneNumber'));
        }
        else if (isNaN(parseInt(phoneCheck))) {
            errorNotify += 'you have entered a letter, please enter a number';
            errorField.push($('#phoneNumber'));
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return isValid;
}
$(function () {
    $('#contact').submit(function() {
        return formVal();
    });
});
```

Comment: btw, unless you're doing this for an exercise, it's well worth using the jQuery validation plug-in: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: Your syntax for the `<label>` element is wrong, `id` isn't a valid attribute - you need to use the `for` attribute and match that with the input elements `id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your ids on the label tags, not the input fields, change

```
<label id="name">Name:</label>
<br>
<input type="text">
```

to

```
<label for="name">Name:</label>
<br>
<input id="name" type="text">
```

etc